# Can't set session data

Tags: codeigniter, session

Maybe this question been answered by someone but i don't know why i can't set session data!

```
$this->load->library('session');

$userdata = array(
      'errors' => 1
);

$this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
redirect('user/profile');
```

when i check the session by `$this->session->all_userdata()`, the session data isn't set. I tried everything, clear my browser's cache, restart my macbook and so on yet i can't set session data.

Comment: This might be a rights issue to your `/tmp` folder. Which *AMP are you using? Or the default built-in Apache/PHP? Final question; are you using database-sessions?

Comment: the missing apostrophe is just a typo?

Comment: yeah, the missing apostrophe before error is a typo... let me correct it

Comment: Good point Christian. But then he would see a fatal error, and the redirect wouldn't take place.

Comment: @Allender : Yes, i am using default built-in Apache/PHP, no i am not using database-sessions

Comment: have you set session encryption key on your config.php?

Comment: @imran : yes, i have set the key, else i will get error asking me to set a key... but the redirect is successfully executed but session data isn't set

Comment: Just for probing; can you test using it without the array *and* using flash data instead of the normal session method. Just to see if it works.

Comment: @allendar, at the beginning i used flashdata... but it doesn't work.. so i use set_data, it should work because i used it before but now i really don't know what's the problem.

Comment: `echo session_id();` see if it's even set. If not there's something wrong with your PHP(settings). You still might want to check if nothing has happened to the tmp-folder's rights for PHP.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the PHP settings all_userdata shows this :

Array
(
    [session_id] => f1ce1c8089ddd254c3b0483fc671f636
    [ip_address] => MY_IP
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
    [last_activity] => 1387720632
    [user_data] => 
)

Comment: maybe $this->session->set_userdata('name', $userdata); ?

Comment: please try it without redirect(), also turn on profiler tool `$this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE);`  Test it in Google chrome. Load page once and hit f5 to reload and in profiler check if your value is set.